# How to fill Joining date and id based on following requirement?

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g

I want to fill the joining date and id by creating a new view and output should be like second image
[image: find the image below][image: output should be like this]

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET tofill.ID          = fillvalues.ID
      ,tofill.JOININGDATE = fillvalues.JOININGDATE
  FROM mytable tofill
  INNER JOIN 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT ID, JOININGDATE, NAME 
      FROM mytable
     WHERE ID           IS NOT NULL
       AND JOININGDATE  IS NOT NULL
  ) fillvalues
  ON tofill.NAME = fillvalues.NAME
  WHERE tofill.ID          IS NULL
     OR tofill.JOININGDATE IS NULL
;
```

I am not familiar with Oracle, but statement should be teh same or similiar

Comment: Unable to execute your query